# Re-casting array to store inside a vector

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a weird problem. I have an array which I need to return to another function. The problem is that it has to be outputted/converted as a

```
(unsigned)(unsigned char)
```

The function which handles the data is a char* type. Here is the function in which I am converting the data:

```
char* Wav::readHeader(ifstream &file)
{
file.read(this->chunkId,                                 4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->chunkSize),     4);
file.read(this->format,                                  4);

file.read(this->formatId,                                4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->formatSize),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->format2),       2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->numChannels),   2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->sampleRate),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->byteRate),      4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->align),         2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->bitsPerSample), 4);

char testing[4] = {0};
int testingSize = 0;

while(file.read(testing, 4) && (testing[0] != 'd' ||
                                testing[1] != 'a' ||
                                testing[2] != 't' ||
                                testing[3] != 'a'))
{

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testingSize), 4);
    file.seekg(testingSize, std::ios_base::cur);

}

this->dataId[0] = testing[0];
this->dataId[1] = testing[1];
this->dataId[2] = testing[2];
this->dataId[3] = testing[3];



file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->dataSize),     4);

this->data = new char[this->dataSize];

file.read(data,                           this->dataSize);

for(unsigned i=0; (i < 20); i++)
{
    //cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)data[i] << endl; 

}

return (unsigned)(unsigned char) data;
}
```

And in another function, I have this:

```
unsigned char* data = this->readHeader(file);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: All those `this->`s are noise. Take them out. That has nothing to do with the vaguely stated problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this->data = new char[this->dataSize];
```

So, presumably, `this->data` has type `char*`. Fine: that's the return type for the function, too. So `return data` seems like the correct code.

Comment: Yes, I store the data as a char, but, then I need to convert it to (unsigned)(unsigned char) otherwise I get negative numbers... Weird

Comment: Then you haven't shown the code that illustrates the problem. But `char` can be a signed type, and reading in a byte with its high bit set will produce a negative value.

Comment: I can output the results to screen, but, only doing (unsigned)(unsigned char) but I don't want to always write this.. Do I have to convert it?

Comment: I'd be inclined to make `data` a pointer to `unsigned char`, allocate it with `new unsigned char[dataSize]`, and cast it to `(char*)` for the call to `read()`. Use `unsigned char` throughout, so you don't get those confusing negative numbers.